# Solution of volume preserving mean curvature flow

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

Consider the volume preserving mean curvature flow 
$$
\partial_tF(x,t)=(h(t)-H(x,t))\cdot\nu(x,t)   ~~~x\in U, t\ge 0   \\
F(\cdot, 0 )=F_0     \\
h(t)=\frac{\int_{M_t}Hd\mu}{\int_{M_t}d\mu}
$$
$F_0:R^n\supset U\rightarrow F_0(U)\subset M_0\subset R^{n+1}$ is local represent of $M_0$ . The relative notation can be saw in **[The volume preserving mean curvature flow](http://pubman.mpdl.mpg.de/pubman/item/escidoc:153469/component/escidoc:153468/332762.pdf)**. Let $A=\{h_{ij}\}$ is the second fundamental form. Then why $\forall m\ge 1$ $|\nabla^m A|^2$ is uniformly bounded $\Rightarrow$ the solution of volume preserving mean curvature flow exists for all time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second fundamental form $A$ is (most of) the second derivative of $F$, and once you have bounds on all derivatives of $F$ the result follows by the Arzela-Ascoli theorem. Going from bounds on $\nabla^m A$ to bounds on $\partial^{m+2} F$  is a little involved - see e.g. Prop 2.4.9 of Mantegazza's *Lecture Notes on Mean Curvature Flow*.

Comment: Thanks , I fail to get the result by Arzela-Ascoli theorem, it is a theorem about uniformly convergent subsequence ,   I don't know how to use it .https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem

Comment: @lanse7pty: suppose the solution exists on $[0,T)$ and take an arbitrary sequence of times $t_k \to T$. Then gradient bounds (which imply equicontinuity) on the functions $F(\cdot, t_k)$ and Arzela-Ascoli imply uniform convergence to some limit, which will be your $F(\cdot, T)$. Higher derivative bounds and a diagonal subsequence argument let you get smooth convergence $F_t \to F_T$ as $t \to T$, so you have a smooth solution on $[0,T]$.

Comment: Thanks, I guess in PDE,  if the equation only has short time solution ,the time of solution existing  must like $[0,T)$. Because it is the singularity  make the solution can't  go on, and singularity come up in a time point.  So, if we can prove the time of solution existing  like $[0,T]$, then, the PDE has solution on all time. I am  right ?

Comment: Well, the solution will exist on *some* interval. If it's a closed interval $[0,T]$, then we can use short-time existence to extend it to $[0,T+\epsilon)$; so the maximal interval will always be of the form $[0,T)$. The estimates + Arzela-Ascoli argument allows us to rule out this as well, and thus the maximal interval must be $[0,\infty)$.